# What is wrong with my code? Why can't I import the router?

Tags: express, router

The error says: `'Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '...\server\router\index imported from \server\index.js`.

I think imported this correctly. I used `"type":"module"` in the package.json. How can I fix this?
[image]

Index:

```or-tag-here
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'
import { router } from './router/index'

dotenv.config()

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 7000
const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(cors())
app.use('/api', router)

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on ${PORT} port`))
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Connection error', e)
  }
}
start()
```

Router:

```or-tag-here
const express = require('express')
import userController from '../controllers/user-controller'

const router = express.Router()

router.post('/registration', userController.registration)
router.post('/login', userController.login)
router.post('/logout', userController.logout)
router.get('/activate/:link', userController.activate)
router.get('/refresh', userController.refresh)
router.get('/users', userController.getUsers)

export { router }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `export deafult {router}` in **/router** module

And in your entry file (index.js) you have to import it like this:

`import {router} from './router'` without **router/index**

Comment: Tried to do that. It didnt help

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: Yes but nothing changed

Comment: 'is not supported resolving ES modules imported...'. I cant import router without index

Answer (score 0):

Finally
in router
export { router }

in index
import { router } from './router/index.js'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).